# Как нарисовать график по координатам на Canvas?

Tags: delphi

У меня есть таблица `Stringgrid1`, состоящая из 2-ух столбцов X и Y, также есть `combobox1`, где показывается сколько `rowcount` в `stringgrid1`. Как нарисовать график по координатам (например, `x=30, 45, 63, 55; y=35, 58, 84, 89;`)?

Т.е. при `combobox1` (1) рисуется точка с координатами `(30,35)`, когда в `combobox1` значение (2), рисуется линия от точки с координатами `(30,35)` к точке `(45,58)` и т.д. Примерный код:

```
for i:=1 to StringGrid1.RowCount-1 do
begin
    image1.Canvas.MoveTo(trunc(x),trunc(y));
    x:=strtoint(stringgrid1.cells[2,i]);
    y:=strtoint(stringgrid1.cells[1,i]);
end
```

Comment: @gamezeldol, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Я не видел вашего Stringgrid`а, поэтому не знаю, есть ли в нем фиксированные ячейки, если есть, то попробуйте так:

```
for i:=1 to StringGrid1.RowCount-1 do
begin
   x:=strtoint(stringgrid1.cells[2,i]);
   y:=strtoint(stringgrid1.cells[1,i]);
   image1.Canvas.LineTo(trunc(x),trunc(y));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[Примеры работы с канвой](http://www.beluch.ru/progr/100comp/4_2.htm).