# Визуализация звука на BASS.dll

Tags: delphi, аудио, bass.dll

Как можно визуализировать звук через BASS.dll на Delphi?
Используя обычный canvas хотя бы, для отрисовки (без всяких spectrum'ов и т.п.)

Хочется сделать что-то типа такого (мгновенное распределение звука по частотам):

[image: желанное]

Comment: @Kromster второе

Comment: Связанные вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676450/Визуализация-звука-с-помощью-библиотеки-bass-на-c?rq=1 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/107042/Как-нарисовать-график-по-координатам-на-canvas

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight В первом вопросе C#, во втором вопрос про отрисовку графика.

Comment: Посмотрите [вот эту ветку на официальном форуме библиотеки](http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=8254.0). Также в [этой ветке форума](http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=15436.0) человек ищет способ как *displays me the spectrum of the intern audio output of the computer*. Там же есть такая многообещающая строчка: *With BASS I could display this by using `BASS_ChannelGetData` for a given audio file*. Может, что-нибудь подойдет.

Comment: Как Вам правильно заметили в ответе, средства для получения FFT-представления звукового канала есть в самой библиотеке. Необходимо применить функцию `BASS_ChannelGetData`, которая *Retrieves the immediate sample data (or an FFT representation of it) of a sample channel*. Советую почитать [вот это](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_ChannelGetData.html) (там же пример использования есть). Справка у библиотеки мощная.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте Фурье-преобразование, чтобы получить частотный спектр. Возможно, средства для этого есть в этой самой bass.dll

Потом получите амплитуду частотного спектра как корень из суммы квадратов мнимой и реальной части

Потом сложите амплитуды в нескольких частотных полосах - при этом обычно используется логарифмическая шкала частот - например, от 20 до 40 Гц, от 40 до 80, от 80 до 160 и т.д.

Полученный массив выведите в виде прямоугольников, высота которых при выводе уровня в децибелах пропорциональна логарифму элементу массива.

Comment: Эм... я хотел бы на примере кода. Что делать понятно, а вот как... это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Так пишите код, показывайте, поможем довести до ума